# Filter a 2 columns of a DataFrame using a dictionary containing lists Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a pandas dataframe of employees that I need to filter based on 2 columns. I need to filter on department and level. So let's say we have department 'Human Resources' and within that it has level 1,2,3,4,5. I'm specifically looking for Human Resources level 2,4 and 5.

I have my desired departments and levels stored in dictionary, for example:

```
departments = dict({'Human Resources' : ['2','4','5'] ,'IT' : ['1','3','5','6'], etc.... })
```

My dataframe will list every employee, for all departments and for all levels (plus lots more). I now want to filter that dataframe using the dictionary above. So in the Human Resources example, I just want returned the employees who are in 'Human Resouces' and are in levels 2, 4 and 5.

An example of the df would be:

```
employee_ID   Department        Level
        001   Human Resources   1
        002   Human Resources   1
        003   Human Resources   2
        004   Human Resources   3
        005   Human Resources   4
        006   Human Resources   4
        007   Human Resources   5
        008   IT                1
        009   IT                2
        010   IT                3
        011   IT                4
        012   IT                5
        013   IT                6
```

Using the dictionary I've displayed above, my expected result would be

```
employee_ID   Department        Level
        003   Human Resources   2
        005   Human Resources   4
        006   Human Resources   4
        007   Human Resources   5
        008   IT                1
        010   IT                3
        012   IT                5
        013   IT                6
```

I have no idea how I'd do this?

Comment: Can you share a sample of your dataframe with expected output?

Comment: something like `df[df[key] in val for key, val in departments.iteritems()]`?

Comment: just added the examples of what I'm looking for

Comment: I dont think that link does answer my question as I want to filter multiple columns

Comment: Also,  Datanovice, That would work if there was only one set of levels I wanted to filter by. I have probably 20 items in the dictionary that I need to apply as filters. So 20 departments, each with about 4 levels I want to filter on.

Comment: Sorry Phil I only saw your dataframes after the edit, my assumption was based off your dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `groupby` on Departement and use `isin` on the Level and get the value for the departement concerned with the name of the group.

```
#example data
departments = dict({'Human Resources' : ['2','4','5'] ,'IT' : ['1','3','5','6']})
df = pd.DataFrame({'Id':range(10), 
                   'Departement': ['Human Resources']*5+['IT']*5, 
                   'Level':list(range(1,6))*2})
#filter
print (df[df.groupby('Departement')['Level']
            .apply(lambda x: x.isin(departments[x.name]))])
   Id      Departement  Level
1   1  Human Resources      2
3   3  Human Resources      4
4   4  Human Resources      5
5   5               IT      1
7   7               IT      3
9   9               IT      5
```

Comment: great answer, I was thinking how to do this in a vectorised manner. in SQL I would create a temp column by concatenating the Department & Level and do the same to the dict and then apply an in clause. not sure if that would be faster than groupby apply

Comment: This looks great! I'm just doing some testing now to ensure I'm getting back what I'm expecting.

Comment: @Ben.T, do you think it would work with an additional category, so department > level > location for example?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215238/discussion-between-phil-collins-and-ben-t).

Comment: If my dictionary looked like 

departments = dict({'Human Resources' : {'Level' : ['2','3','5'], 'Job Title' : ['Admin','Manager','Engineer']}, 'IT' : {'Level' : ['1','5'], 'Job Title' : ['Analyst','Dev','Manager']})

what amendments to the code would I make to return all these employees?

Comment: @Ben.T apologies! didn't see that, I'll respond in that chat now. Thanks!